# Let's get critical: Aug 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Open Data Stack Exchange](http://opendata.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: The site is dying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How to use the DOI system as an individual?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/827/how-to-use-the-doi-system-as-an-individual)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Database of English words pronunciation](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/840/database-of-english-words-pronunciation)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [What is the significance of Census ACS columns with line numbers ending in ".5" or ".7"?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/891/what-is-the-significance-of-census-acs-columns-with-line-numbers-ending-in-5)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Open data for international treaties](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/802/open-data-for-international-treaties)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Open Seed for Crawl](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/812/open-seed-for-crawl)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Linking results from the FCC's TV Query API to the FCC's TV Stations Profiles API](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/847/linking-results-from-the-fccs-tv-query-api-to-the-fccs-tv-stations-profiles-ap)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Is there a resource to look up the Standard Industrial Classification codes that companies file with the SEC?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/857/is-there-a-resource-to-look-up-the-standard-industrial-classification-codes-that)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Who are non-schema.org data standards for?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/900/who-are-non-schema-org-data-standards-for)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Programatically request recent close prices for a list of stock tickers](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/910/programatically-request-recent-close-prices-for-a-list-of-stock-tickers)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Wikipedia table to JSON (or other machine-readable format)](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/823/wikipedia-table-to-json-or-other-machine-readable-format)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)